# Why are all segues missing their animations?

Tags: ios, animation, segue

I'm programming an iOS app with Swift4.
Suddenly all segues stopped animating. Animation is turned on, everywhere I perform a segue. (If programmatic or in IB.)

My best guess is that it has something todo with main- and background-queues, but I have no idea.

I don't really know which information you could need. Just tell me and I'll update the question.

Here's my storyboard. (So you have any idea of what I'm doing.):
[image: Storyboard, segues and filetree]

Comment: Try to reset/restart your Simulator/Device

Comment: @JD Yes, thank you! "Turning it of and on again" worked  I'm kinda embarrassed of my self. So I guess it had something to do with the memory???

Comment: Not at all but sometimes Xcode/Simulator stuck with this type of problem.